# Im doing free() of invalid pointer, but can't detect the error

Tags: c, pointers, free

I get an error that I free an invalid pointer.

consider size as 100 (maximum number of words), and `max_str_len` as 50 (max number of letters in a word, doesn't contain '\0'. the function is set to scan a sentence and store every word in words array.

```
int read_words(char* words[], int size, int max_str_len){
    int wordsCounter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <size; ++i) {
        words[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(max_str_len+1));
        if(words[i]==NULL){
            //in case of failure it frees every word.
            for (int j = 0; j <i ; ++j) {
                free(words[j]);
            }
            return MALLOCERROR;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j <max_str_len+1; ++j) {
            if(scanf("%c", &words[i][j])==EOF){
                wordsCounter++;
                words[i][j]='\0';
                if(j<max_str_len)
                    free(&words[i][j+1]);
                return wordsCounter;
                }
            if (words[i][j]==' ') {
                words[i][j] = '\0';
                if(j<max_str_len)
                    free(&words[i][j+1]);
                break;
            }
        }
        wordsCounter++;

    }
    return wordsCounter;
}
```

Comment: One way to find out is to always NULL out any pointer just after you free it. Ex: `free(words[j]); words[j] = NULL;`  Then any improper reuse will fail sooner.

Comment: ... but if only `words[n]` is obtained from allocated memory, why are you freeing `words[i][j+1]`? This doesn't look like it was malloc'd at all.

Comment: @SteveFriedl notice that the words[i] points at (max_str_len + 1) sized array. im using free to get rid of unused memory by the malloc and it happens if j < max_str_len. which means that i didnt get a max_str_len word. i think this is what you asked about

Comment: that's not how it works: the ONLY pointer you can provide to `free()` is a pointer you got from `malloc()` or `realloc()` - you can't go to (say) byte 80 and say "I don't want that byte any more".  You can use `realloc()` to resize an array up or down, but it must always operate on the original pointer from the allocator.

Comment: @SteveFriedl to be pedantic you can also `free` a pointer returned by `calloc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see what's going on here; you're allocating a large buffer, reading into it, and if you didn't need all that space for the word, then you want to give back the memory. That makes sense.

You can't tell the allocator: free starting from position  but we can do almost the same thing with `realloc()`, which takes a pointer and resizes the array, possibly moving it to a new location. In your case of shortening an array, it should work really well.

Instead of

```c
if (j < max_str_len)
    free(&words[i][j+1]); // INVALID
```

try

```c
if (j < max_str_len)
    words[i] = realloc(words[i], j+1);   // +1 for the NUL byte
```

This should do what you're looking for.